# Webpack TerserPlugin ignoring drop_console in production?

Tags: javascript, webpack

After updating the Webpack packages to its latest version. I have noticed that the TerserPlugin is ignoring console.log in production and showing it.

Even after setting it to FALSE in production.

Tried looking on Google and on Github but couldn't find a solution.

My Package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@splidejs/splide": "^2.4.14",
    "ascii-art-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.4",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "browserslist": "^4.14.3",
    "chokidar": "^3.4.2",
    "clean-terminal-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "css-loader": "4.3.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.9.0",
    "eslint-loader": "4.0.2",
    "extra-watch-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.3",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.0",
    "hard-source-webpack-plugin": "^0.13.1",
    "imagemin-mozjpeg": "^9.0.0",
    "imagemin-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.11.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "postcss": "8.0.7",
    "postcss-100vh-fix": "^1.0.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.5.0",
    "progress-bar-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "10.0.2",
    "source-map-loader": "^1.1.0",
    "stylelint": "^13.7.1",
    "stylelint-declaration-use-variable": "^1.7.2",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.18.0",
    "stylelint-use-nesting": "^3.0.0",
    "stylelint-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.0",
    "stylelint-z-index-value-constraint": "^1.1.0",
    "suppress-chunks-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.6",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "webpack": "4.44.2",
    "webpack-build-notifier": "^2.1.0",
    "webpack-config-utils": "^2.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "^2.2.0",
    "webpack-plugin-hash-output": "^3.2.0",
    "webpack-remove-chunk-entry": "^1.0.0"
},
```

This is my Webpack plugin:

```
const { THEME_AUTHOR, THEME_NAME, ASCII_TEXT, ASCII_FONT, HOST, PORT } = require('./env.config');

const path = require('path');
const chokidar = require('chokidar');
const paths = require('./paths.config');
const pkg = require('../package.json');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const date = new Date();

// Plugins
const { AsciiArtWebpackPlugin } = require('ascii-art-webpack-plugin');
const HardSourceWebpack = require('hard-source-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtract = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const styleLint = require('stylelint-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpack = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const FriendlyErrorsPlugin = require('friendly-errors-webpack-plugin');
const WebpackBuildNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-build-notifier');
const CleanTerminalPlugin = require('clean-terminal-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const Imagemin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;
const imageminSvgo = require('imagemin-svgo');
const imageminMozjpeg = require('imagemin-mozjpeg');
const SuppressChunksPlugin = require('suppress-chunks-webpack-plugin').default;

// Config utils
const { removeEmpty, getIfUtils } = require('webpack-config-utils');
const { NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const { ifProduction, ifDevelopment } = getIfUtils(NODE_ENV);

module.exports = {
    target: 'web',
    mode: ifDevelopment ? 'development' : 'production',
    devtool: 'eval-cheap-module-source-map',

    devServer: {
        /**
         * Watch for changes to PHP files and reload the page when one changes.
         */
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        before(app, server) {
            const files = ['**/*.php'];

            chokidar
                .watch(files, {
                    atomic: false,
                    ignoreInitial: true,
                    ignorePermissionErrors: true,
                    persistent: true,
                    usePolling: false
                })
                .on('all', () => {
                    server.sockWrite(server.sockets, 'content-changed');
                });
        },
        quiet: true,
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        open: true,
        writeToDisk: true,
        compress: true,
        public: `http://${HOST}:${PORT}`,
        host: HOST,
        port: PORT,
        proxy: {
            '**': {
                target: `http://${HOST}`,
                secure: false
            }
        }
    },

    stats: {
        colors: true,
        hash: false,
        version: false,
        timings: false,
        assets: false,
        chunks: false,
        modules: false,
        reasons: false,
        children: false,
        source: false,
        errors: false,
        builtAt: false,
        errorDetails: false,
        entrypoints: false,
        warnings: false,
        publicPath: false
    },

    optimization: {
        minimize: ifProduction(true, false),
        namedModules: ifDevelopment(true, false),
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
        noEmitOnErrors: true,
        removeAvailableModules: true,
        removeEmptyChunks: true,
        splitChunks: {
            hidePathInfo: true,
            chunks: 'all',
            maxInitialRequests: 5,
            maxAsyncRequests: 7,
            name: THEME_NAME,
            cacheGroups: {
                default: {
                    enforce: true,
                    priority: 1,
                    minChunks: 2
                },
                vendors: {
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendors',
                    enforce: true,
                    priority: 2
                }
            }
        },

        minimizer: [
            new TerserPlugin({
                test: /\.js(\?.*)?$/i,
                parallel: 4,
                sourceMap: ifDevelopment(true, false),
                terserOptions: {
                    output: {
                        comments: false
                    },
                    compress: {
                        drop_console: ifProduction(true, false)
                    }
                },
                extractComments: false,
                exclude: /\/node_modules/
            })
        ]
    },

    entry: {
        main: [paths.entry.js(), paths.entry.styles()]
        // editor: paths.entry.WPeditor(),
        // admin: paths.entry.WPadmin(),
    },

    output: {
        path: paths.output.base(),
        filename: paths.filename.js()
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtract.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            url: false
                        }
                    },
                    'postcss-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sassOptions: {
                                indentWidth: 4
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },

            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader']
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: removeEmpty([
        ifDevelopment(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()),

        // new SuppressChunksPlugin([
        //     { name: 'admin', match: /\.js$/ },
        //     { name: 'editor', match: /\.js$/ },
        // ]),

        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            // Write Logs to Console
            verbose: ifDevelopment(true, false),

            // Automatically remove all unused webpack assets on rebuild
            cleanStaleWebpackAssets: true,

            cleanAfterEveryBuildPatterns: ['!*.+(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf|TTF|OTF)'],

            // Do not allow removal of current webpack assets
            protectWebpackAssets: true
        }),

        new styleLint({
            configFile: '.stylelintrc',
            context: paths.styles(),
            files: '**/*.s?(a|c)ss'
        }),

        new MiniCssExtract({
            filename: paths.filename.styles()
        }),

        new CopyWebpack({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: paths.images(),
                    to: paths.output.images(),
                    noErrorOnMissing: true,
                    globOptions: {
                        dot: false,
                        ignore: ['**/.gitkeep']
                    }
                },

                {
                    from: paths.fonts(),
                    to: paths.output.fonts(),
                    noErrorOnMissing: true,
                    globOptions: {
                        dot: false,
                        ignore: ['**/.gitkeep']
                    }
                }
            ]
        }),

        ifProduction(
            new Imagemin({
                cacheFolder: './.cache-images',
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$/i,
                pngquant: {
                    quality: '80-85',
                    speed: 4
                },

                plugins: [
                    imageminMozjpeg({
                        quality: 50,
                        progressive: true
                    }),

                    imageminSvgo({
                        plugins: [
                            {
                                removeViewBox: true,
                                removeTitle: true,
                                removeXMLProcInst: true,
                                removeComments: true,
                                removeMetadata: true,
                                cleanupEnableBackground: true,
                                convertStyleToAttrs: true,
                                convertPathData: true,
                                convertTransform: true,
                                removeUselessStrokeAndFill: true,
                                cleanupIDs: true,
                                moveElemsAttrsToGroup: true,
                                mergePaths: true,
                                convertShapeToPath: true,
                                sortAttrs: true,
                                addClassesToSVGElement: true,
                                reusePaths: true
                            }
                        ]
                    })
                ]
            })
        ),

        new AsciiArtWebpackPlugin({
            text: ASCII_TEXT,
            font: ASCII_FONT,
            extensions: ['js', 'css']
        }),

        new HardSourceWebpack({
            environmentHash: {
                root: process.cwd(),
                directories: [],
                files: ['package-lock.json', 'yarn.lock']
            },

            info: {
                mode: 'none',
                level: 'error'
            },

            // Clean up large, old caches automatically.
            cachePrune: {
                // Caches younger than `maxAge` are not considered for deletion. They must
                // be at least this (default: 2 days) old in milliseconds.
                maxAge: 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                // All caches together must be larger than `sizeThreshold` before any
                // caches will be deleted. Together they must be at least this
                // (default: 50 MB) big in bytes.
                sizeThreshold: 50 * 1024 * 1024
            }
        }),

        new FriendlyErrorsPlugin(),

        new CleanTerminalPlugin(),

        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(NODE_ENV),
            'process.env.VERSION': JSON.stringify(pkg.version)
        }),

        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(true),

        new webpack.BannerPlugin({
            banner: `Copyright ${date.getFullYear()} ${THEME_AUTHOR} All Rights Reserved - v${
                pkg.version
            }\n${pkg.description}\nLast updated: ${date.getDate()}/${
                date.getMonth() + 1
            }/${date.getFullYear()} (${date.getHours()}:${('0' + date.getMinutes()).substr(-2)})`,
            exclude: /(vendors|runtime)\.js/i
        }),

        ifDevelopment(new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin()),

        ifDevelopment(
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                exclude: /(vendors|runtime)\.js/i
            })
        ),

        ifDevelopment(
            new WebpackBuildNotifierPlugin({
                title: `${THEME_AUTHOR}`,
                sound: false,
                suppressSuccess: true
            })
        )
    ])
};
```

Answer (score -2):

Figured it out. Devtool was causing this issue in production to display all console logs and ignoring the Terser option drop_console.

Comment: What do you mean? Did you figured out how to remove console.logs in production?